# Why does the Visual C++ compiler think "abstract" is a valid keyword on unmanaged classes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

While writing an unmanaged C++ class, I accidentally put the "abstract" keyword on the class.  It built just fine on Visual C++.

```
class CommChannel abstract  {};
```

But since this unmanaged code also builds on Linux, it caused a compiler error with gcc.

Given my Visual C++ compiler settings (VS2022), I would have expected it Visual Studio to at least warn me about it. I have these settings

- compiler set to the C++/17 standard (`/std:c++17`)
- conformance mode ***on*** (`/permissive-`)
- warning **level 4** (`/W4`)
- treat warnings as errors ***yes*** (`/WX`)
- the only disabled warnings are

  - 4251 - *'type' : class 'type1' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'type2'*
  - 4275 - *non - DLL-interface class used as base for DLL-interface class *
  - 4100 - *'identifier' : unreferenced formal parameter*
  - 4714 - *function  marked as __forceinline not inlined"*
  - 4505 - *'function' : unreferenced local function has been removed*

In fact, not only does Visual C++ fail to complain about it, the word `abstract` even shows up in blue, just like all the truly valid C++ keywords do (e.g. `virtual` `class`, `public`, etc).

If I click on the "abstract" keyword and hit the F1 key it takes me to help about the C++/CLI `abstract` keyword.  But this is not C++/CLI code.  And if I click on it and choose "go to definition", nothing happens so I don't think anyone is just `#define`-ing the word "abstract" away to nothing.

1. Does anyone know why Visual C++ would let this build without even a warning?
2. Is there a compiler setting I can set to make this be caught?

Comment: Heh, interesting, also even with all language extensions disabled (`/Za`) and all warnings enabled (`/Wall`) it does not complain. A quick search on developercommunity shows, that `abstract` is not the only statement that is incorrectly treated as a keyword in pure C++: [`sealed`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-nonstandard-CCX-sealed-keyword/10123550?q=abstract+keyword) is also affected.

Comment: Gonna report it, OP?  I think there's an entry in the Help menu for that

Comment: Ignore ``/Za`` as it's ancient and not really updated in any meaningful sense. ``/permissive-`` is the important switch these days. Please report this as a bug.

Comment: @PaulSanders I went to the help section and found the post that @Sedenion mentioned about the `sealed` keyword.  They're investigating it.  I added a comment about the `abstract` keyword doing exactly the same thing